# AWS QLDBSessionClient sendCommand fails

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-sdk, amazon-qldb

I'm trying to send commands to a ledger on Amazon QLDB using [this  package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK.QLDBSession/) on .net core 3 but the QLDBSessionClient.sendCommand() appears not work...

I follow [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/getting-started-driver.html) but on .net core nuget package has no **execute()** method.

Anyone has a sample that show how can i sendCommand to my ledger to create tables and indexes from my c# code?

Ps: unfortunately, [github repository](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/) has no documentation and no samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** The QLDB .NET driver is now available in preview. Please see https://www.nuget.org/packages/Amazon.QLDB.Driver. The getting started tutorial is available at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/getting-started.dotnet.html.

QLDB does not currently have a driver for .NET. The 3 supported languages are: Java, Python and Node.js.

What you have found is low level bindings to the QLDBSession API. This, by itself, is not nearly enough to get you using QLDB. We publish the source code for these drivers on GitHub, e.g. https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-qldb-driver-java, for cases where customers are willing to implement a driver themselves, but in general we do not recommend doing that.

Please note that .NET is one of the languages that we hear a lot about from customers. I'm not able to share a date with you, but I will come back to this post when we do have something to share.

I'm sorry we're not able to accommodate you right now.

Comment: I've updated my answer @CarlosOliveira. There is a .NET driver now available.